# Javascript Regex Split Statement Keeping Delimiters and Storing in Object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I have a string like this:

`(IF 20 EQUALS 'Yes' AND 30 [Choice 2] EQUALS 'No') OR 50 EQUALS 'Yes'`

I need to deliminate based on `AND` or `OR`

So that it comes out with an array of objects that look like this:

```
$scope.conditions = [
 {
  condition: `20 EQUALS 'Yes'`,
  prefix: ' ( ',
  postfix: ' && '
 },
 {
  condition: `30 [Choice 2] EQUALS 'No'`,
  postfix: ' ) ||',
 },
 {
  condition: `50 EQUALS 'Yes'`
 }
]
```

I already wrote a routine which handles the `conditions` but I need to get the array of objects looking like this in order to loop through it correctly, this is a simple programming language that's being written for people with basic programming skills to process some forms.

I tried this:
`var conditionFactors = condition.split(/([()]|AND|OR)/);`

To split it up, but the array length was different and when I went through the loop to update the object of each array item it became messed up.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

First, I would refactor your data structure to look like this:

```
$scope.conditions = {
    left: {
        left: `20 EQUALS 'Yes'`,
        right: `30 [Choice 2] EQUALS 'No'`, 
        operator: '&&'
    },
    right: `50 EQUALS 'Yes'`,
    operator: '||'
};
```

That way, parentheses and grouping is less confusing. To parse the string, you could use a recursive function in pure JS; but an easier approach is to use a parser library such as [PEG.js](https://pegjs.org/).

Comment: The inital data cannot be altered.

Comment: I can parse the final data just fine, the problem is getting it into that format.

Comment: @Jordash Yes I mean the final data. Have you looked at PEG.js?

Comment: Yes, how would I get the final data into the format you suggest from the initial data?

Comment: The initial data is this: `(IF 20 EQUALS 'Yes' AND 30 [Choice 2] EQUALS 'No') OR 50 EQUALS 'Yes'`